# Chaining streaming APIs in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, audio-streaming, google-translation-api

I need to receive an audio stream, get a transcription then stream the transcription to another service, it could be translation or natural language API; the need is to process whe input voice stream continuously
Is there anyone with idea/suggestions about how to pass the speech API output as input to another dowsnstream API?

Answer (score 0):

If we look here,

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize

We find some useful information on receiving a stream of speech to text transformation.  What appears to happen is that one registers a callback and when a "chunk" of translated text is processed, the callback is invoked passing in the translated audio as a textual representation.  It is at this point that you now have a unit of text that would then be your responsibility to process.  From your description, it seems that you would then invoke your downstream API passing in the received text.